# Java List diplay

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have following method

```
private List<Utente> elencoUtenti() {
    List<Utente> utenti = new ArrayList<Utente>();    
    utenti.add(new Utente("Piero", "Bianchi", 45, "Roma", "info@pierobianchi.it", "test"));
    utenti.add(new Utente("Mario", "Rossi", 40, "Roma", "info@mariorossi.it", "test"));
    return utenti;
}
```

I want then display the content of the list but I don't know how I can do it with multiple string within one array box.
What I mean, utenti[0] should contain 
"Piero", "Bianchi", 45, "Roma", "info@pierobianchi.it", "test"
how to display that in Java?
BR
M.

Comment: To display that where?

Comment: Override `Utente` `toString()`

Comment: normally it'll show the reference value of List when you print. To dispaly the value you need to `iterate` the List

Comment: sorry, simple output with system.out.println()

Comment: You probably want to write a method `public String toString() { ... }` in your `Utente` class,  that descries exactly how a `Utente` object appears when it's printed out.  Once you've done that, you can either call `toString` explicitly, or just use `System.out.println` to print your objects.

Comment: How is the entity `Utente` defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override toString

```
private List<Utente> elencoUtenti() {
    List<Utente> utenti = new ArrayList<Utente>();

    utenti.add(new Utente("Piero", "Bianchi", 45, "Roma", "info@pierobianchi.it", "test"));
    utenti.add(new Utente("Mario", "Rossi", 40, "Roma", "info@mariorossi.it", "test"));


    return utenti;
}
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Utente{" +
                "firstname=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", emps=" + emps +
                '}';
    }
public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<Utente> li = elencoUtenti();
    for(Utente u : li) {
        System.out.println(u);
    }
}
```